# Select throwing error WSAENOTSOCK

Tags: c++

**ISSUE THAT I AM FACING**:-

Select(..) API is throwing error when called with FD_SET set containing  IPv6 and IPv4 sockets on Win7 Home premium but the same application is running fine on other win7 machine. But if i use only IPv6 or IPv4 socket in FD_SET then it runs fine. So i think, system support both IPv6 and IPv4.

I tried using the server from the link below :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Even this sample is same error from select call.

Anyone can please help me in getting the reason behind this error and solving this issue.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows does not permit mixing sockets from different providers in the same call to `select`. This is because each provider is permitted to implement its own `select` handler.

> The sockets contained within the fd_set structures must be associated with a single service provider. -- [select function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Windows will pick a provider to send the `select` to (I believe the provider of the first socket in the set), and that provider will not recognize the other provider's sockets. Honestly, you shouldn't be using `select` anyway -- it's just provided for compatibility with the BSD sockets interface. It's definitely not the "Windows way".

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
I am using multiple address family socket IPv4 and IPv6 of TCP type. I think in this case service provider is same. It is same as in windows IPv6 compatible server as in link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Select is the standard way to get the socket on which request is 
actually received.I think there is some other reason might be related to LSP that is causing this problem.

Comment: I got the reason behind this error. A installed network s/w is adding its LSP in socket layer. This LSP is causing this failure.

Comment: I wish I could say I was surprised.